# NHibernate passing parameter in criteria

Tags: nhibernate, ms-access, criteria, icriteria

I have an Ms Access view(query) as following

```
select * from employee Where EmployeeId=SomeID
```

Here **SomeId** is **not** a field name

If I run this query from MsAccess 
It prompts me for entering value for SomeId as follows

```
|---------------------------------------|
| Enter Parameter Value               X |
|---------------------------------------|
| SomeId                                |
| [_________________________________]   |
|                                       |
|                [  OK  ] [ Cancel ]    |
-----------------------------------------
```

and executes the query based on the same.

Now My question is how can I pass this SomeId using Criteria in Nhibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EmployeeId", someId)).List<Employee>();
```

or

```
session.Load<Employee>(someId);
```